# Reveal [Semantic UI] in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

My goal is to convert some of the code here http://jsbin.com/qipufujibi/edit?html,output to Semantic UI React.

This is my attempt:

```
<Card>
    <Reveal animated='fade'>
        <Reveal.Content visible>
            <Image src="imgSrc"/>
        </Reveal.Content>
        <Reveal.Content hidden>
            <Card.Content>
                <h3>Minions</h3>
                <Card.Meta>
                    <span className='date'>2015</span>
                </Card.Meta>
                <Card.Description>
                    Matt
                </Card.Description>
            </Card.Content>
            <Card.Content extra>
                <a>
                    <Icon name='user' />
                    22 Friends
                </a>
            </Card.Content>
        </Reveal.Content>
    </Reveal>
</Card>
```

However, it does not work properly. 
It loses the style https://i.imgur.com/Ypx5Nag.gifv. How can I fix it?

Comment: You probably have to provide a full code snippet, since nothing about styles provided in a question

Comment: @Vlad That is the full code. There is nothing more to it. The styles from Semantic UI is gone. If you look at the Semantic UI in HTML (link 1) it works very well. But problems occur when I do the same thing in React (link 2). Is the conversion properly done?